# Button Click JQuery does not work

Tags: jquery, button, click

I'm having troubles with my button click in JQuery. I have to post the values of the input fields via AJAX but the button click it self doesn't even work.

When I log to the console it doesn't register the button click.

Can you guys help me out please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>AJAX calls to Servlet using JavaScript and JSON</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tasks to do</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="give task's name" name="name" id="name" /> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="give task's summary" name="summary" id="summary" /> 
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
    </form>
    <br/>

    <h1>Here are the open tasks 2</h1>
    <div id="open"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(".submit").click(function(){
          $("#open").html = "Button clicked";
        }); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#open").html ( "Button clicked");

Comment: `$("#open").html = "Button clicked";` should be `$("#open").html("Button clicked");`

Comment: @DeepakMankotia Also there is a class named "submit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct change `.html =` to `.html(htmlCode)` . Read documentation of **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method in jQuery for better understanding

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    $("#open").html("Button clicked");
    //        -----^-----
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tasks to do</h1>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="give task's name" name="name" id="name" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="give task's summary" name="summary" id="summary" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
<br/>

<h1>Here are the open tasks 2</h1>
<div id="open"></div>
```

Or you can use **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    $("#open")[0].innerHTML = "Button clicked";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tasks to do</h1>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="give task's name" name="name" id="name" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="give task's summary" name="summary" id="summary" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
<br/>

<h1>Here are the open tasks 2</h1>
<div id="open"></div>
```

Comment: The OP is claiming that the handler doesn't even run

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will help you. register the control first.

Use this script outside the document ready function

```
$(document).on('click','.submit',function(){
    $("#open").html("Button clicked");
});
```

OR

```
$(document.body).on('click','.submit',function(){
    $("#open").html("Button clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
$("#open").html = "Button clicked";
```

to

```
$("#open").html("Button clicked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".submit").click(function(){
    $("#open").html("Button clicked");
  }); 
});
```

And you can use console.log() to check if the function works or not. You can see the `Open Developer Tools`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".submit").click(function(){
    console.log("Button clicked");
  }); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hxp4472h/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $("#submit").click(function(){
          $("#open").html = "Button clicked";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing wrong with button click in your code. It will work perfectly, you can verify it by using alert method instead of updating div.
2. The way you are trying to update your div is wrong. here is the correct way of doing it: $("#open").html('Button clicked').
   Note: html() is a method not property.